# remove URL link ie11

Tags: javascript, html, url, onclick, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible to remove the URL of a link from showing in the bottom left hand corner in IE11 as in the image below

I have created a JSFiddle of the code

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1xLzeq3d/)

```
<A href="#" onclick="Q_CancelEvent();if (!ImageHelp.disabled) {ShowHelpFile();}" onkeypress="alert('KEYPRESS');" ondragend="Q_CancelEvent();ImageHelp.QButtonDown=false;if (ImageHelp.disabled) {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aCB.gif';}else {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ4ts.gif';}" ondeactivate="ImageHelp.QHasFocus=false; ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yftsq.gif';" onactivate="if (!ImageHelp.disabled) {ImageHelp.QHasFocus=true;if (!ImageHelp.QButtonDown) ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yftsq.gif';}" accessKey=H><IMG onmouseup="ImageHelp.QButtonDown=false;if (ImageHelp.disabled) {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yftsq.gif';}else {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yftsq.gif';}" onmouseover="if (!ImageHelp.disabled) {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ4ts.gif';}" onmousedown="if (!ImageHelp.disabled) {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aCB.gif';ImageHelp.QButtonDown=true;}" onmouseout="if (!ImageHelp.disabled) {if (!ImageHelp.QHasFocus) {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aCB.gif';}else {ImageHelp.src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aCB.gif';}}" border=0 name=ImageHelp alt="View Online Help" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aCB.gif" width=70 height=25></A>
```

[IE11 URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF7Fd.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of the browser that is not controllable by the end-user. This feature allows the consumer to identify the source of a link, prior to clicking it. The label may move around at times, depending on where the link is in relation to the tooltip.

This is a standard feature across all major browsers.